# Snotty made a joke I don't understand

Tags: humor, spaceballs

I have always had a nagging question about the transporter scene in SpaceBalls.

After Skroob has been "transported", to his then asinine state, we see Snotty "try and reverse the beam".

> Snotty: Hold on, sir. We'll try and reverse the beam. Could be the interlocking system.
>
> SKROOB scratches his leg.
>
> Snotty: (flipping switches) Lock 1, Lock 2, Lock 3, **Lock lone**.

I have highlighted the part I was not sure about. In the case of "lock lone" is there a joke or technical reference there? I don't understand that and wanted to know if I was missing something.

The following youtube video contains the scene in question. You can also just [skip to the section I have quoted above](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etY7kbRRQ_c&t=2m8s).

[image: Good ol Snotty]

Comment: I would like to think that there was some effort put into this question. If anyone has theories as to why I got a downvote I would love to hear it so that I know for next time.

Comment: Loch = Lake in Scots Gaelic.

Comment: Who else clicked to this question because 'Snotty' looked like 'Scotty' @Trekkies

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Given that the character is a Scottish stereotype, I suspect he's saying "Loch Lomond", which features in the title and verses of the famous Scottish song [The Bonnie Banks o' Loch Lomond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bonnie_Banks_o%27_Loch_Lomond) (which many will recognize from the verse "you take the high road and I'll take the low road"):

I double checked on the blu-ray, which has an "English for the deaf and hard of hearing" subtitles option in "setup" on the menu, and the subtitles read "Lock one. Lock two. Lock three. Loch Lomond!"

Comment: I thought it was weird that the sound didn't match the screenplay I found.

Comment: Another error in the transcript you quoted--Skroob wasn't scratching his *leg* in that scene! ;)

Comment: I let that one go. Didn't want to write that one out.

Comment: My copy of the movie was without subtitles and I just assumed everything I read on the internet was true!

Answer (score 24):

Yeah, it's a reference to [Loch Lomond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loch_Lomond)! At least, according to the English subtitles of the DVD!

[image: The subtitled scen from Spaceballs: The Movie]

In both the German and the Italian dub of the movie - anyway - Snotty's joke is translated as:

> Lock 1, Lock 2, Lock 3... Loch Ness!

From the name of the [Scottish lake which should host Nessie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loch_Ness) (see the Italian version of the gag [here](https://youtu.be/LmQ-FuVJlpg?t=3m)).

In the original version, he's instead (as already mentioned) saying "Loch Lomond" (see [the movie English script here](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=spaceballs) - **disclaimer:** as @Richard commented, this site is far from completely reliable, but this part is identical to the English subtitles in the movie's DVD).

**Side note / personal opinion on the adaptation:** I suspect that this is due to the fact that Loch Ness is more famous in those countries than any other Scottish lake, thus making the joke easier to understand. Notice, however, the difference is only in the dub: the subtitles say Loch Lomond instead of Loch Ness for both versions.

Comment: You may want to note that the springfieldspringfield link is an automatic transcription and is frequently incorrect.

Comment: @Richard uhm... right. I've not thought about it. I have the movie with the subtitles and checked it, maybe I could see if I can post a picture instead.

Comment: @Richard Now I have added a proper picture ;)

Comment: And you shall have my +1

Comment: Loch Ness is probably more famous than Loch Lomond in most countries, but the rhythm of the line would sound wrong if they chose that.  Mainly because "Ness" is one syllable, and would more likely go unnoticed than the two syllable "Lomond" in that context.

Comment: I can't completely agree with you, @DarrelHoffman. In both the non-English versions I have watched, the "Loch Ness" part is easily understandable and - I swear - it doesn't go unnoticed :')

Comment: Alright, as someone who doesn't speak Italian or German, I'll have to take your word for it.  However, my original point still stands, I think - Loch Ness is almost certainly more widely known in most of the world.  (You'd have to ask a Scotsman which is more famous in Scotland, but that's not the point I think.)

Answer (score 11):

He says "Loch Lomond".
**Loch** is the Scottish word for "lake".
**[Loch Lomond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loch_Lomond)** is one such lake.
It's a joke because he's Scottish, and "Loch" sounds like "Lock".

Comment: I feel bad for not knowing that since I am half Scottish. Thanks

Comment: @Matt - Loch Ness. :)

Comment: "Loch" only sounds like "Lock" is you are *not* Scottish. If you are really Scottish, they sounds quite different. Although of course they also sound the same if you are speaking with a terrible fake Scottish accent.

Comment: @DJClayworth Not quite true. _Loch_ only sounds like _lock_ if you pronounce them the same. Doesn’t matter if you’re Scottish or not. Some Scots pronounce both /lɒk/, and some non-Scots (like me) pronounce _lock_ /lɒk/ and _loch_ /lɒx/. And of course some Scousers would pronounce them both /lɒx/.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: So you're saying DJ's claim was a particularly literal example of the [No True Scotsman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman)! :-)